# PHP MySqli How to fix insert file with path in database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, file-upload

i'm inserting the path of the file (pdf) to the database and i'm saving the file to a folder ( files/contracts ). 
I'm doing something wrong since in my database (i'm using phpmyadmin ) under contracts it is showing like this: "**files/contracts/TEST5.pdf**" with the path to the folder. Also when i list it it is showing the path. Can you please help me?

This is the code i'm using for inserting:

```
$contract_path = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'files/contracts/'.$_FILES['contractupload']['name']);

if (copy($_FILES['contractupload']['tmp_name'], $contract_path)){

$sql = "INSERT INTO addemployees (fname, lname, dob, embg, address, city, mobile, email, workplace, workposition, jobstartdate, contractfrom, contractto, healthbookfrom,
                                  healthbookto, contractupload, bankaccount, bank, workcode, gender, bloodtype, notes)
        VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$dob', '$embg', '$address', '$city', '$mobile', '$email', '$workplace', '$workposition', '$jobstartdate', '$contractfrom', '$contractto',
                '$healthbookfrom', '$healthbookto', '$contract_path', '$bankaccount', '$bank', '$workcode', '$gender', '$bloodtype', '$notes')";
```

This is all code:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "bale";
$pass = "blagojce";
$dbname = "employees";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
$dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dob']);
$embg = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['embg']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$workplace = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['workplace']);
$workposition = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['workposition']);
$jobstartdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['jobstartdate']);
$contractfrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contractfrom']);
$contractto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contractto']);
$healthbookfrom = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['healthbookfrom']);
$healthbookto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['healthbookto']);
$bankaccount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bankaccount']);
$bank = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bank']);
$workcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['workcode']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['gender']);
$bloodtype = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bloodtype']);
$notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['notes']);
$contract_path = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'files/contracts/'.$_FILES['contractupload']['name']);

if (copy($_FILES['contractupload']['tmp_name'], $contract_path)){

$sql = "INSERT INTO addemployees (fname, lname, dob, embg, address, city, mobile, email, workplace, workposition, jobstartdate, contractfrom, contractto, healthbookfrom,
                                  healthbookto, contractupload, bankaccount, bank, workcode, gender, bloodtype, notes)
        VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$dob', '$embg', '$address', '$city', '$mobile', '$email', '$workplace', '$workposition', '$jobstartdate', '$contractfrom', '$contractto',
                '$healthbookfrom', '$healthbookto', '$contract_path', '$bankaccount', '$bank', '$workcode', '$gender', '$bloodtype', '$notes')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  header("location: employees.php");

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

}
else {
    $_SERVER['message'] = 'File upload failed!';
}

//Close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: `copy` should be http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: That's what you told it to store.

Comment: [Why is *“Can someone help me?”* not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: It inserts the path to the file to the database. And i dont know what i'm doing wrong or how to fix it. 
Please see the screenshots: 

https://i.imgur.com/g0NDBCz.png

https://i.imgur.com/7wP8eMJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it to store `$contract_path` in the database, and on the previous line you set this to a path that begins with `files/contracts`.

If you want to store just the filename, put that in a different variable:

```
$contract_file = basename($_FILES['contractupload']['name']);
$contract_path = "files/contracts/$contract_file";
$contract_file = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $contract_file);
```

Then use `$contract_file` instead of `$contract_path` in the `INSERT` query.

BTW, it would be better to use parametrized queries instead of substituting variables into the query, even if you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar that worked :) But now instead of saving the files to the folder:  "files/contracts" it saves them to the main folder. 
How can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why does it do that? You weren't supposed to change the filename in `copy()`. BTW, you should use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`.

Comment: Upss :) Thank you very much @Barmar, that fixed my issue :) 

If i can ask you one more question please:

Now, how can i show the file that i uploaded to my table ( the actual file so when i click on it, it can open in new tab/download )?

This is my code: [code](https://i.imgur.com/s1dlQSn.png)  Thanks a lot

Comment: Write a `download.php?id=XXX` script, and add a link to that script around the filename.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barmar.